# How to continue execution of background process in this scenario

Tags: bash, unix, background-process

I have 3 process a.sh, b.sh, c.sh that are executed in background.

```
./a.sh &
pid_a=$!

./b.sh &
pid_b=$!

./c.sh &
pid_c=$!
```

I need to ensure that all three processes run till the longest process terminates. If c.sh takes 10 secs, a.sh takes 3sec, b.sh takes 5sec for individual execution times, I need to execute a.sh, b.sh again to ensure that they exist till c.sh finishes.

I was trying this approach which certainly doesn't work in the above scenario

```
 ./a.sh &
 while ps -p $! > /dev/null; do

./b.sh &
 pid_b=$!

./c.sh &
pid_c=$!

wait $pid_c
done
```

How do I get this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use temporary files as flags to indicate when each process completes for the first time. Run each script in a background loop until each of the other two have completed at least once.

```
flag_dir=$(mktemp -d flagsXXXXX)
flag_a=$flag_dir/a
flag_b=$flag_dir/b
flag_c=$flag_dir/c

( until [[ -f $flag_b && -f $flag_c ]]; do ./a.sh; touch $flag_a; done; ) &
( until [[ -f $flag_a && -f $flag_c ]]; do ./b.sh; touch $flag_b; done; ) &
( until [[ -f $flag_a && -f $flag_b ]]; do ./c.sh; touch $flag_c; done; ) &

# Each until-loop runs until it sees the other two have completed at least one
# cycle. Wait here until each loop finishes.
wait

# Clean up
rm -rf "$flag_dir"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use `kill -0` to test the status of the process for `c.sh`, rather than using `wait` to wait for it to terminate.

Second, you can use 2 separate processes to monitor the state of scripts `a.sh` and `b.sh`

Third, this assumes that `c.sh` is the longest running process.

Thus, monitor process 1 does the following:

```
# I have pid_c
./a.sh &
pid_a=$!
while wait $pid_a; do
    if kill -0 $pid_c; then
        ./a.sh&
        pid_a=$!
    fi
done
```

and monitor process 2 does the following:

```
# I have pid_c
./b.sh &
pid_b=$!
while wait $pid_b; do
    if kill -0 $pid_c; then
        ./b.sh &
        pid_b=$!
    fi
done
```

Thus, you're monitoring the 2 processes separately. However, if you need to monitor them as well, then spawn the monitors as 2 background jobs and a simple `wait` will wait on `c.sh` as well as the 2 monitors.

Note: `kill -0 $PID` returns `0` if `$PID` is running or `1` if `$PID` has terminated.

Comment: Works fine, but in my problem, I don't know in advance which is the longest running process !! Hence, I cannot assume that.

Answer (score 0):

[**Note** This works for bash only. *ksh93* `kill` behaves differently.]

As long as there's at least one process you are allowed to kill, `kill -0` will return success.  Tune the interval as needs be.

```
#! /bin/bash
interval=1
pids= && for t in 2 3; do
    (sleep $t && echo slept $t seconds) & pids=${pids:+$pids }$!
done

while (kill -0 $pids) 2>& -; do
    sleep $interval
    # optional reporting:
    for pid in $pids; do
        (kill -0 $pid) 2>&- && echo $pid is alive
    done
done
```

Results in:

```
6463 is alive
6464 is alive
slept 2 seconds
[1]-  Done                    eval sleeper $t
6464 is alive
slept 3 seconds
[2]+  Done                    eval sleeper $t
```

---

Builtin `kill` is not consistent regarding errors:

```
$ ksh -c 'kill -0 571 6133 && echo ok || echo no'
kill: 571: permission denied
no
$ bash -c 'kill -0 571 6133 && echo ok || echo no'
bash: line 0: kill: (571) - Operation not permitted
ok
```